# No text is shown when using PdfFileReader

Tags: python, web-scraping, pypdf

So suppose I'd like to extract the text from a pdf file such as this one:
https://www.lyxoretf.nl/pdfDocuments/Factsheets/RFACT_FR0010377028_EN_20190131_NLD.pdf?pfdrid_c=false&uid=4cc6aef9-9e75-46d7-9416-65cd7b2b5dd6&download=null

```
import io
import requests
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

url = 'https://www.lyxoretf.nl/pdfDocuments/Factsheets/RFACT_FR0010377028_EN_20190131_NLD.pdf?pfdrid_c=false&uid=4cc6aef9-9e75-46d7-9416-65cd7b2b5dd6&download=null'

r = requests.get(url)
f = io.BytesIO(r.content)

reader = PdfFileReader(f)
contents = reader.getPage(0).extractText().split('\n')
```

Using the code provided in related links unfortunately doesn't return the text in the file.

Is there a way to extract the text from these types of files?

Comment: Do you want it to read online only or storing 1st in your local system and then reading it will also work ?

Comment: I would like to be able to access the data in for instance the Trading Information table in my python script.

Comment: Sorry didn't understand you!! Also, any information present in a table in pdf will come as a line item wise. There is no way a table can come as a table in converted text only

Comment: Ok, so what I mean is the following: Is there a way to access the data in the table 'Trading Information'? I don't necessarily need the information in a table format, but the text in the table (for example, on the upper right part of the page you see Ticker :   LYJPN SW), can I access that somehow through python?

Comment: You can use that, provided this particular pdf is somewhere stored in your computer/laptop/system. I am posting an answer for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import fitz     ## pip install PyMupdf  
path = r'\Factsheets_RFACT_FR0010377028_EN_20190131_NLD.pdf' ## This should be stored somewhere in your system/laptop/computer
text=""
doc = fitz.open(path)
for page in doc:                            
    text+=(page.getText())
```

Answer (score 0):

`pypdf` has improved a lot in 2022. Give it another shot:

```py
from io import BytesIO
import urllib.request

import pypdf

url = "https://www.amundietf.nl/download/f510d5bd-9e87-4ddd-b3af-dc62dc6fca3e/MonthlyFactsheet_2053760_13166_NLD_ENG_ETF_INSTITUTIONNEL_20221031.pdf"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

# creating a pdf reader object 
reader = pypdf.PdfReader(BytesIO(data)) 
    
# printing number of pages in pdf file 
print(len(reader.pages)) 
    
# creating a page object 
page = reader.pages[0] 
    
# extracting text from page 
print(page.extract_text())
```